# Array and CALL dynamic_array in SAS SQL

Tags: sas

I'm having trouble with understanding this piece of code:

```
array arname[1] / nosym;
call dynamic_array(arname,10)
```

Does the first line create a one-dimensional array and the second one creates a multidimensional (10) array?

Comment: If that is SAS then it is probably part of PROC FCMP and has nothing to do with normal SAS syntax or SQL syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement defines `arname` as a temporary array with 1 element.

The second statement redefines `arname` as an array with 10 elements.  The existing elements are preserved.

Resizeable arrays are only possible within the context of a `FCMP` function or call routine, and are not part of the DATA Step language.  `FCMP` functions can be invoked from DATA Step or Proc SQL.

[Proc FCMP ARRAY Statement](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/pl/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p048tu5gixqaxin1ej7b7yuyhn86.htm)

> /NOSYMBOLS is used in exactly the same way as _TEMPORARY_.

[FCMP Special Functions and Call Routines - CALL DYNAMIC_ARRAY Routine](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/pl/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/n0ht4c42g9m027n1fbd67lu2y8ws.htm)

> CALL DYNAMIC_ARRAY(array–name, new-dimension1–size <, new-dimension2–size, ...>);
> ...
> The DYNAMIC_ARRAY CALL routine attempts to dynamically resize the array to match the dimensions of the target that you provide. This means that the array must be dynamic. That is, the array must be declared either in a function or subroutine, or declared with the /NOSYMBOLS option.